# RegEx: First three characters unique + additional match

Tags: java, objective-c, regex, passwords, policy

I am looking to achieve a password policy with RegEx.

The policy contains of these rules:

1. First three characters must be unique
2. Password must be at least 8 characters long
3. Password must contain at least one letter, one digit and one special-character (of white-list)

I found this pattern that matches 1):

`^(.)((?!\1).)((?!\1)(?!\2).)((?!\1)(?!\2)(?!\3))`

This pattern matches 2) and 3):

`^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-].*)(.{8,})`

Now I am stuck combining these two pattern into one. Can someone help here please? ;-)

Comment: you may want to consider something that is not a regex.

Comment: i there a reason why you cant apply multiple regexs?

Comment: No, I just thought it might be a good idea to combine all conditions into one pattern. The same validation should be used on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, don't combine them into one. Just check each of the 3 regexes one at a time. Combining them is going to be scary and incomprehensible if you ever need to add new rules, or change existing rules (especially since you're already having trouble combining them).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1)(?!\2))(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-])(.{8,})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI5kG9/1)

```
(?=(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1)(?!\2)) # Makes sure first 3 characters are unique using lookaheads
```